# Rails 6 Filterrific Syntax Error in _list.html.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I'm following as closely as I can to set up simple filtering on a players model using http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/action_view_api.html as an example. However, I keep getting the syntax error below, clearly I'm missing something here!

Error

```
syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')'
  </div>
  ^
/home/jack/Itorix/app/views/players/_list.html.erb:10: unknown regexp options - th
```

Players Controller

```
def index
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
      Player,
      params[:filterrific]
    ) || return
    @players = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page])
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Players Model

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
    filterrific(
        default_filter_params: { sorted_by: 'tornid' },
        available_filters: [
     :sorted_by,     
   ])
      scope :sorted_by, ->(sort_option) {
  # extract the sort direction from the param value.
  direction = /desc$/.match?(sort_option) ? "desc" : "asc"
  case sort_option.to_s
  when /^tornid/
    # Simple sort on the created_at column.
    # Make sure to include the table name to avoid ambiguous column names.
    # Joining on other tables is quite common in Filterrific, and almost
    # every ActiveRecord table has a 'created_at' column.
    order("players.tornid #{direction}")

  else
    raise(ArgumentError, "Invalid sort option: #{sort_option.inspect}")
  end
}
end
```

Index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Players</h1>

<% js = escape_javascript(
  render(partial: 'players/list', locals: { players: @players })
) %>
$("#filterrific_results").html("<%= js %>");

<%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f| %>  
  <div>
    Sorted by
    <%= f.select(:sorted_by, @filterrific.select_options[:sorted_by]) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= link_to(
      'Reset filters',
      reset_filterrific_url,
    ) %>
  </div>
  <%# add an automated spinner to your form when the list is refreshed %>
  <%= render_filterrific_spinner %>
<% end %>

<%= render(
  partial: 'players/list',
  locals: { players: @players }
) %>
<%= link_to "New Player", new_player_path %>
```

_list.html.erb

```
<%# app/views/players/_list.html.erb %>
<div id="filterrific_results">

  <div>
    <%= page_entries_info players # provided by will_paginate %>
  </div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><%= filterrific_sorting_link(@filterrific, :tornid) %></th>
    </tr>
    <% players.each do |player| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= player.tornid %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>

<%= will_paginate players # provided by will_paginate %>
```

Comment: can you provide code where  `filterrific_sorting_link` is declared?

Comment: It's part of the filterific gem

Comment: Did you get filterrific working with Rails 6?

Comment: @hashrocket, not in rails 6 no, started afresh in 5 with no issues

Comment: I would love to know how people get this working in Rails 6!

Comment: @Chris, the answer below works for rails 6 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just came across this issue and solved it by removing the inline comments in the _list file. Remove the `# provided by will_paginate` from both `page_entries_info` and `will_paginate` and the syntax errors go away.